# Extrinsic Read Smartcontract Data

Tags: pallet-contracts, contracts

I would try to replicate the Extrinsics that is thrown when using this

[image]

This is the ABI of my smart contract

```json
{
        "args": [
          {
            "label": "code",
            "type": {
              "displayName": [],
              "type": 2
            }
          }
        ],
        "default": false,
        "docs": [],
        "label": "get_track",
        "mutates": false,
        "payable": false,
        "returnType": {
          "displayName": [
            "ink",
            "MessageResult"
          ],
          "type": 12
        },
        "selector": "0x43f80da1"
      }
```

This is the call I'm trying to make

https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.shibuya.astar.network#/extrinsics/decode/0x46060053edb57f71f35eb471296511e015b306cbe36295341b59883b4844536d265ef9000002093d00009043f80da1542d53484952542d353234333133000000000000000000000000000000000000

[image]

```
1011: Unknown Transaction Validity: UnknownTransaction::NoUnsignedValidate
```

**EDIT:  Some progress (with ContractsApi_call)**

```
{"id":22,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"state_call","params":["ContractsApi_call","0x9a0a3d999ba84d10f3257dc5616a0679cb60f56d4ae24f7b2357d25bfa7a450f8836bb46beaf9bb701f4aea16a7b9f448166bee6629d572d24a397c53739c5260000000000000000000000000000000000009043f80da1542d53484952542d353234333133000000000000000000000000000000000000"]}
```

```
0x
Origin (Addr Caller): 9a0a3d999ba84d10f3257dc5616a0679cb60f56d4ae24f7b2357d25bfa7a450f
Destination (SmartContract): 8836bb46beaf9bb701f4aea16a7b9f448166bee6629d572d24a397c53739c526
????? = 00000000000000000000000000000000000090
Selector (method from abi) = 43f80da1
Code (parms smartcontract) = 542d53484952542d353234333133000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Now i messing only to understand  the 00000000000000000000000000000000000090 value

Comment: "mutates": false, it's a readonly call, probably another method to call in these cases?

Comment: I have to call a method of my smart contract, it is not mutable so I have to make a read-only call, the call info is all contained in the json that I extracted from the ABI. From polkadotjs it returns the data to me and makes the call without asking me to sign the transaction, unfortunately since there is no Tx to sign, I have no idea what call I'm making to get this data

Comment: What's the problem? Is it that you are unable to replicate the read from polkdaotJS in your code?

Comment: yes i have to replicate that call for the build of my library which interfaces with node. So I need to figure out which is the right call in this case